# AspNet Core issue when deployed in ubuntu server

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, key-management

I have several aspnet core applications served in Ubuntu server (16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64)), Those applications always have worked very well, they are webapi configured very similar each other, but yesterday I have a problem publishing one of them (just one the other work like a charm), I received an error that honestly I don't understand mostly because I don't recall have done any change related to the error message, I've wasted many hours and I'm going to crazy. I recently upgrade aspnet core version from 1.1 to 2.0.

This is my Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Webtools Service";

        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", true)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, conf) =>
            {
                var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
                // delete all default configuration providers
                conf.Sources.Clear();
                conf.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                conf.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                conf.AddJsonFile("appsettings.local.overrides.json", optional: true);
                conf.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            //.UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

I attach the error trace:

```
> info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>       User profile is available. Using '/home/ubuntu/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys
> will not be encrypted at rest. Application startup exception:
> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Principal functionality
> is not supported on this platform.    at
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.ApplicationFolderProvider..ctor(IDictionary
> environment, String folderName)    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.Transmitter.Initialize()
> at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration
> configuration)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TelemetryConfigurationOptionsSetup.Configure(TelemetryConfiguration
> configuration)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TelemetryConfigurationOptions..ctor(IEnumerable`1
> configureOptions)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.<>c.<AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry>b__13_1(IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
> factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite
> enumerableCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder
> app)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication() crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>       Application startup exception System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Principal functionality
> is not supported on this platform.    at
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.ApplicationFolderProvider..ctor(IDictionary
> environment, String folderName)    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.Transmitter.Initialize()
> at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration
> configuration)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TelemetryConfigurationOptionsSetup.Configure(TelemetryConfiguration
> configuration)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TelemetryConfigurationOptions..ctor(IEnumerable`1
> configureOptions)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.<>c.<AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry>b__13_1(IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
> factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite
> enumerableCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder
> app)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
> 
> Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows
> Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.    at
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.ApplicationFolderProvider..ctor(IDictionary
> environment, String folderName)    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.Implementation.Transmitter.Initialize()
> at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration
> configuration)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TelemetryConfigurationOptionsSetup.Configure(TelemetryConfiguration
> configuration)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.TelemetryConfigurationOptions..ctor(IEnumerable`1
> configureOptions)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.<>c.<AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry>b__13_1(IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
> factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite
> enumerableCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite
> scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite
> singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder
> app)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
> WebtoolsService.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in
> /var/NetWebApps/sources/Program.cs:line 26    at
> WebtoolsService.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /var/NetWebApps/sources/Program.cs:line 16
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out this issue is caused by ApplicationInsights I updated to version 2.2.0-beta1 and according to https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/551 it has a bug that causes platform issues, I just installed version 2.1.1 and that fixed the problem.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
```